# How is energy conserved in a system involving centrifugal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, centrifugal-force

Assuming there are two pieces of machines that are used to simulate kicking soccer balls. The machines are identical to each other except for the lengths of "leg" that is used to kick soccer balls, i.e. one machine (calling it Machine A) has a longer "leg" than than the other (calling it Machine B). The "leg" kick soccer by making a circular movement for the same amount of angular motion (like a fan). The "leg"s in both machines are powered in the same way with the same energy input (for simplicity, I assume that both machine are powered by dropping an object weighing 100 kg by 1 meter; i.e. the gravitational potential energy (=> kinetic energy) of the object is used to power the "legs").

Since Machine A has longer "leg" than Machine B, so the linear velocity of Machine A's leg will be higher than Machine B and the ball (Ball A) kicked by Machine A will have higher acceleration (i.e. ball kicked by Machine A gains more energy (kinetic and elastic (due to e.g. deformation)) than the one kicked by Machine B).

However, the energy input into both Machine A and B are the same, so where does difference in energy between Ball A and Ball B go for Ball B?

Comment: How can you assume "Both machines are powered in the same way with the same energy output " This assumption is wrong,

Comment: How about it now?

Comment: @Aqqqq “... the linear velocity of Machine A's leg will be higher than Machine B ...” - no, it won’t. If the energy used is the same for both machines the “boot” end of the legs will have the same linear velocity.

Comment: @gandalf61 In both cases, the angular velocity should be the same (since the weight will be dropped at the same acceleration/ speed), so why is linear velocity not the same?

Comment: @Aqqqq Equal energy does *not* mean equal angular speed. A pirouetting skater increases their angular speed by bringing their arms and legs closer to their body, but their total energy does not change.

Comment: @gandalf61 I am not talking about equal energy, I am talking about the weight is dropped at the same acceleration/ speed for both machine in this case.

Comment: @gandalf61 But angular velocity should be the same. Also "Equal speeds of the falling weights does not mean equal leg speeds if the legs have different lengths." That is exactly my point, which is why I am asking where does the difference in kinetic energy goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since Machine A has longer "leg" than Machine B, so the linear
> velocity of Machine A's leg will be higher than Machine B

That is not correct.

The linear velocity of the "boot" end of each leg and the linear velocity of each soccer ball will be the same when the ball and boot separate. The acceleration of the boot end of leg A will be less than the boot end of leg B, but will act over a longer distance than leg B resulting in the same final linear velocity of each. This is necessitated by conservation of energy. Consider the following:

The kinetic energy of each ball is the result of the net work done by the leg of each machine on the ball per the work energy principle, or

$$\Delta KE_{a}=F_{A}d_{A}$$

$$\Delta KE_{b}=F_{B}d_{B}$$

Where

$\Delta KE_a$ and $\Delta KE_b$ are the kinetic energies given soccer balls $a$ and $b$

$F_A$ and $F_B$ are the forces exerted by the ends of legs A and B, and

$d_A$ and $d_B$ are the distances over which the forces $F_A$ and $F_B$ act on soccer balls $a$ and $b$.

Since the source of energy for each leg is the same, from conservation of energy (assuming no losses or equal losses) the work done by each leg will also be the same, all other things being equal. Therefore,

$$F_{A}d_{A}=F_{B}d_{B}$$

Although the ends of both legs undergo the same angular displacement in radians, the force applied by the end of the longer leg A acts over a longer distance (length of the arc) than the shorter leg B, therefore

$$d_{A}>d_{B}$$

Which in turn, for the same amount of work done by both legs, means the force exerted by the longer leg A has to be less than the shorter leg B or

$$F_{A}<F_{B}$$

The acceleration imparted to soccer ball $a$ by leg A is thus less than that imparted to soccer ball $b$, but acts over a longer distance (and time). The end result is the final linear velocity of the end of each leg, and thus the departing velocity (and kinetic energy) of each soccer ball, will also be the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I am a bit even more confused because in this video (https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1GS4y1M7Kg  (it is in Chinese; for comparison between different leg length, look at 2:23 (shorter) and 3:40 (longer))) someone made such a machine, and at 3:24 they explained that with longer "leg", the soccer ball would have greater velocity and hence cover greater distance. And the soccer ball indeed covered greater distance comparing to when the machine's leg was shorter. Do you know the reason behind it?

Comment: Since I don't speak Chinese, I have no idea how the demonstration was set up. I can't tell if the foot in each case had the same angular displacement which would effect the horizontal component of the departure velocity and thus distance traveled.

Comment: According to the video, the angular displacement is constant: always 170 degree.

Comment: Measured from where?

Comment: Fro what I could see it was around 45deg from the horizontal

Comment: From the start of the kick (you can see that the "leg" is very exagerratedly pointing upwards at the back of the figurine) to where the kick ends (the "leg" is at the "standing position"). I would say the angular displacement are always constant.

Comment: Are you saying the legs are pulled to the back and released for a total angle of swing of 170 deg?

Comment: Does the video really say, that the machine has the same energy? And of cause the energy the machine supplies during contact is higher t depends of the momentum, the foot can supply, not from the energy it uses in the time of contact, and the energy used during contact is higher if the arm is longer. If you consider only the constant energy the machine uses while not pushing anything, this does not imply that it is the same all it pushes something.

Comment: @BobD 170 deg was what the video says. From the video itself I could see that the total angle of swing should be the same no matter the leg length.

Comment: @Aqqqq was the energy source a torsion spring?

Comment: @trula is your comment to me or Aqqq, because I have no idea what the video is saying since it’s in Chinese

Comment: @BobD It is spring, not torsion spring. At 3:03, the blue parts are the 4 springs.

Comment: @trula Sorry I missed your comment. I am not sure if I understood your comment correctly but for your first question: The video tried twice with the same machine. The only difference between the two trials is that the "leg length". So in both trial the energy inputs are the same.

Comment: @Aqqqq Torsion spring or regular spring, its potential energy is the only energy source for the soccer ball.  The leg begins and ends at rest so its change in kinetic energy is zero. So I can't understand how the speed (kinetic energy) of the ball kicked by the long leg can be more than the short leg. The only reason I can think of for the ball going further with the longer leg is the launch angle was less than the short leg, i.e., the height reached by the short leg was higher than the long leg. I do notice that the initial position of the ball is higher for the short leg.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a short duration impulse during the kick from a “boot” with mass on the end of a “mass-less” arm, the machine will deliver the same energy to the boot (before the kick) for any length of arm.

Comment: Then why is the speed of Ball A greater the speed of Ball B?

Comment: The two boots are given the same energy and have the same impact speed. The machine applies a given torque through a given angle. The boot on the longer arm experiences a smaller accelerating force but travels along a longer arc.  (The two boots are not on the same arm at the same time.) Both balls receive the same impulse and leave with the same speed.